# Twitter Bootstrap 3 form control does not work with safari

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, passwords

```
<div class="form-group">
        <!-- Password-->
<label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Consider following snippet. It complies with tb3. The problem is whenever I try to type anything into this field in safari - nothing gets written inside. Blinking cursor becomes active on field input during typing but no characters/black dots appear inside the field.

ff, chrome and even ie work ok. Basically on the picture I type but cursor stays at the same place no input at all.

I turned off all my scripts and problem still persists. If I change type to text it starts to work or if I remove form-control it works. But both are required...

**Safari version 5.1.7 - version for windows**

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I implemented in my case is adding this line of CSS to element

```
.SafariFix{
    -webkit-user-select:auto;
}
```

here is HTML of button

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search by name" class="btn btn-default SafariFix" id="friendsearchinput">
```

note (this will work for safari 6 but I am not sure for previous version )

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that I used

```
padding: 20px 13px;
```

which caused issues on the input element. The input text and the placeholder weren't visible in Safari, but worked in any other browser.

I fixed it by using

```
padding: 0 13px;
height: 45px;
```

which looks the same but works in Safari.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem: You could try to change the `font-family` of the password input field, for example:

```
style="font-family:Arial"
```

and then it should work as expected :-)